# I am getting this specific error of error when creating ".\\deployment_test.yaml": Deployment in version "v1" cannot be handled as a Deployment

Tags: kubernetes, yaml

I am trying create deployment using yaml file in **kubernetes** but facing this specific error:

**Error from server (BadRequest): error when creating ".\deployment_test.yaml": Deployment in version "v1" cannot be handled as a Deployment: v1.Deployment.Spec: v1.DeploymentSpec.Template: v1.PodTemplateSpec.ObjectMeta: v1.ObjectMeta.Labels: ReadMapCB: expect { or n, but found ", error found in #10 byte of ...|"labels":"test"},"sp|...**

My yaml file is as follows:

```
kind: Deployment
metadata:
    labels:
      environment: test
    name: agentstubpod-deployment
spec:
  replicas: 3
  selector: 
    matchLabels: 
      enviroment: test
  minReadySeconds: 10
  strategy: 
    rollingUpdate: 
      maxSurge: 1
      maxUnavailable: 0
    type: RollingUpdate
  template: 
    metadata:
      labels: test
    spec: 
      containers:
      - name: agentstub
        image: some-repo:latest 
---
apiVersion: apps/v1
kind: Deployment
metadata:
    labels:
      environment: test
    name: proxystubpod-deployment
spec:
  replicas: 3
  selector: 
    matchLabels: 
      enviroment: test
  minReadySeconds: 10
  strategy: 
    rollingUpdate: 
      maxSurge: 1
      maxUnavailable: 0
    type: RollingUpdate
  template: 
    metadata:
      labels: test
    spec: 
      containers:
      - name: procyservice
        image: some-repo:latest
```

What is wrong with this syntax? I am having a really hard time making a deployment

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are some misconfigurations.

1. apiVersion is missing in the first deployment
2. indentation below `metadata` is incorrect
3. You must include the `metadata.name` field
4. `spec.selector.matchLabels` and `spec.template.metadata.labels` should be matched.

Here is the corrected example:

```yaml
apiVersion: apps/v1
kind: Deployment
metadata:
  labels:
    environment: test
    name: agentstubpod-deployment
  name: dep1
spec:
  replicas: 3
  selector:
    matchLabels:
      environment: test
  minReadySeconds: 10
  strategy:
    rollingUpdate:
      maxSurge: 1
      maxUnavailable: 0
    type: RollingUpdate
  template:
    metadata:
      labels:
        environment: test
    spec:
      containers:
      - name: agentstub
        image: some-repo:latest

---
apiVersion: apps/v1
kind: Deployment
metadata:
  labels:
    environment: test
    name: proxystubpod-deployment
  name: dep2
spec:
  replicas: 3
  selector:
    matchLabels:
      environment: test
  minReadySeconds: 10
  strategy:
    rollingUpdate:
      maxSurge: 1
      maxUnavailable: 0
    type: RollingUpdate
  template:
    metadata:
      labels:
        environment: test
    spec:
      containers:
      - name: procyservice
        image: some-repo:latest
```